# Ghostscript to PDF invalid character

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Within a c# application, we are using Ghostscript v9.05 to convert a post script file to pdf. The process works in live and also locally on a Windows 7 machine. We are however in the process of moving to new environments and whilst testing on a new Windows Server 2012 environment the pdf's are being generated with Ü displaying instead of the letter h. (If i copy and paste the Ü from the pdf, it does actually paste as a letter h)

The font that we are using is Tahoma and the command line that is running is...
gswin64 -dpdfsettings=/prepress -dnopause -sfontpath="C:\Windows\Fonts" -sdevice=pdfwrite -soutputfile="c:\filename.pdf" -dbatch "c:\filename.ps"

I am wondering if anyone else has experienced something similar?

Comment: Have you compared the Tahoma fonts from the involved machines with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try using current code, the current release is 9.18, 9.05 is now 3 years old. Secondly, you need to post an example file so that we can look at it.

Finally, don't use -dPDFSETTINGS, that sets an enormous number of controls. If it doesn't exhibit whenm you don;t set that, then you'll need to experiment to see which particular control caused the problem, though I'd bet it makes no difference. Always try to minimise command lines in Ghostscript, it makes investigation **much** easier.

Your best bet is probably to open a bug report.

Comment: Upgrading the version to 9.18 fixed the issue - thanks.